# How do I remove the header/footer of some pages?

Tags: microsoft-word

I created a template in Word 2010. In this template, there is a footer and a header. When I create a document based on this template, I'd like for some pages not to show them.

Comment: Haven't you got the answer you were looking for, since you haven't accepted?

Comment: If you use LibreOffice writer to edit this document, you can apply different page styles to different pages. One page style can have headers and footers and another can omit them. You can then save your document in any one of a number of Word formats. This is probably the easiest and most flexible method for handling issues like this.

Answer (score 11):

Use `section breaks`.

Place each part of your document that requires a different header/footer in separate `sections`, by adding "Next page" section-breaks (Page layout -> Breaks -> Section breaks -> Next page).

Then, for each section, insert header/footer. When editing header/footer, "de-click" the button "Link to previous" in the toolbar. That indicates that this header/footer will be different from the header/footer of the previous section. Then edit the header/footer, affecting only this section (possibly also the next ones, but *not* the previous). Do this for all sections.

Comment: This didn't work for me with a page break. But it did work when I inserted a continuous break just above the page break.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  I'm sure it will help. [Remove Header or Footer from the Second Page of a Word 2007 Document](https://team.utb.edu/sites/helpdesk/Knowledge%20Base/Remove%20Header%20or%20Footer%20from%20the%20Second%20Page%20of%20a%20Word%202007%20Document.aspx)

> - Click on the first page of your document (within the body).
> - Go to the Page Layout tab on the ribbon (third tab) and click on the tiny arrow in the lower right of the Page Setup group to expand it (see image).
>
>   [image: Ribbon view]
> - Click on the Layout tab (third tab).
> - Check the “Different first page” checkbox.
> - Ensure that the “Apply to” field is set to “This point Forward.”
> - Click on OK.
>
>   [image: Dialog box]

Comment: Having a link is nice, but in the future, include all relevant parts here on site, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that Microsoft has excluded any away to specifically pick which **individual** page to show or not show the header or footer. Here the few limited options available: effect all pages at once; effect odd and even pages differently; effect the first page differently from the rest; the combination of all these.

#### How to configure heading and footer differently depending the page:

- Select the **Laytop** tab from the ribbon
- [Click] on either *Header* or *Footer*
- Select the wanted design
- Notice under the sub tab of **Design** there are check boxes: (*See Note 1*)

  - Different First Page
  - Different Odd & Even Pages (*See Note 2*)
  - Show Document Text (*Can be disregarded since it's not related this subject.*)
- Select the wanted settings

***Note 1:** These choices will effect both the footer and header. Exampe: It isn't possible to have different odd & even pages selected for header with out having different odd & even pages selected for the footer too. Additionally, to have all the pages effected the same, remove the check marks from both choices.*

***Note 2**: When first editing an odd or even page the heading or footer will effect both types pages even if **Different Odd & Even Pages** is selected. Do not worry, after finishing with the current page header or footer, select the next page and make your changes. Once this has been done, all old pages will be the same as will the even ones.*

Comment: not possible to use "Breaks" (Page, Section Breaks) ?

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting?

Comment: I guess you can take advantage of page-breaks, different odd & even page option, and print page selection. Example: Select have the different odd & even page option. When want to have back-to-back pages with the same header, just put a blank page in between the two pages via a page-break. When ready to print, select **only** the pages that are not blank. I guess you could do it that way. If that was what you were referring too.

Comment: @Kris-I Section breaks is probably what you want -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the page breaks function. I made a page break, then removed the header from that page (page 3 for me), made a page break after that page and copy/pasted the original header from my 1st/2nd page to page 4.